Having troubles expanding touchable country picker component in react native
When I installed a country picker from react-native-country-picker-modal, the  component is a clickable input field, however it is a very small pressable element. I cant seem to enlarge it even with a touchableopacity and hitslop. What may be any alternative ways to fixing this to allow me to expand my touchable area? Thanks
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
} from "react-native";
import CountryPicker from "react-native-country-picker-modal";

const CountryCodePicker = () => {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(null); // Default selected country code
  const onSelect = (selectedCountry) => {
    setCountry(selectedCountry);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>Country/Region</Text>

      <CountryPicker
        withFlag={false}
        style={styles.picker}
        onSelect={onSelect}
        placeholder=""
      />
      {country && (
        <>
          <Text style={styles.countryText}>{country.name}</Text>
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 50,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#ccc",
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  label: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: -10,
    left: 10,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    zIndex: 1,
    color: "#aaa",
  },
  picker: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 10,
    backgroundColor: "white", // Add a background color to the picker
  },
  pickerOpen: {
    height: 40, // Adjust height when picker is open
  },
  countryText: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    color: "#333",
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "400",
    lineHeight: 24,
  },
});

export default CountryCodePicker;

